# How to remove all radio button elements from DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This my half of the HTML code:

```
<fieldset class="amenities"> 
    <legend>Amenities</legend>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <ul id="amenities">
        <li class="amenity ">
            <input class="am-input" type="checkbox" name="jform[amenities][]" id="jform_amenities0" value="95"  />
            <label class="am-title" for="jform_amenities0" ></label>
        </li>
        <li class="amenity ">
            <input class="am-input" ...............
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$("label[for='jform_amenities5']").addClass("selected");
$("fieldset input:radio").remove();​
```

This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9fVTN/).

I just want to remove all radio buttons from the site. I used the `.remove()` function but nothing happened. How can I do this ?

Comment: There are no radio buttons in your fiddle.

Comment: You have to search for the elements you *have* that you want to remove. You have `:checkbox` *not* `:radio`. If you use the right selector your code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the checkbox with label having text = radio you have to do something like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/9fVTN/3/)**

```
$("label[for='jform_amenities5']").addClass("selected");
lbl = $("fieldset label:contains('Radio')");
$('#'+ lbl.attr('for')).remove();
$("fieldset label:contains('Radio')").remove();​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If you want to remove the type = radio which you tried in code then you have to use   checkbox instead of radio as there is not radio control in your code

```
$("label[for='jform_amenities5']").addClass("selected");

$("fieldset input:checkbox").remove();​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/9fVTN/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using *checkboxes*, not radio buttons. Thus, either set the input *type* to `checkbox`:

```
$("fieldset input[type='checkbox']").remove();​
```

Or use the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector, which is equivalent:

```
$("fieldset input:checkbox").remove();​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FSETq/)**.